# Finding the boolean from a table of random integers compared to a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, boolean

Inputs are:

1. A Panda Dataframe with 500 columns and 10 lines, which contains a series of random integers comprised between 0 and 10000 (included)
2. A list of 10 random integers comprised between 0 and 10000

The output I am looking for is:

A Panda Dataframe with 500 columns and 10 lines, which gives the Boolean true or false depending if the element from the x-th line is above (true) or below (false) the number which is the x-th element of the list

I was able to solve this in excel using the following functions:

1. =RANDARRAY(10,1,0,10000,TRUE)
2. =IF(RANDARRAY(10,500,0,10000,TRUE)>A1,TRUE,FALSE)

Is there an elegant way of producing this solution in python? I am still a beginner learning more about python.

Thank you for the help

Update: Using MSS's solution, this is my final code. Could you please tell me if there are any mistakes in my code?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10000,size=(10, 500)))
df.head

list = random.sample(range(10000), 10)
print(list)

a = df.to_numpy()
b = np.array(list) 
res = pd.DataFrame(a > b[:,None], index= df.index, columns=df.columns)
print(res)
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: This will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this way using numpy.

```
a = df.to_numpy() # Dataframe of shape (10,500)
b = np.array(your_list) # your_list contains 10 random numbers >=1 and <=10000
res = pd.DataFrame(a > b[:,None], index= df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Lets explain using a smaller dataframe having 3 lines and 5 columns and a list having 3 numbers. All numbers are random between 1-9.

```
inter = np.array([[1,2,3,5],[4,5,6,1],[7,8,9,5]])
df = pd.DataFrame(inter)
your_list = [3,6,7]
```

The output obtained after applying above code is:

```
    0       1       2       3
0   False   False   False   True
1   False   False   False   False
2   False   True    True    False
```

Hence solution is correct.

Comment: If it helps, please accept it as correct by clicking on tick.

Comment: how do I deal with the rows and columns being labelled in numbers and being considered in the result?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by it ?

Comment: In your example, the row and column numbers are considered in the result. In the random number dataset, I don't think this is an issue.

Comment: You can take any random numbers in any range say from 100 to 300. It will not come in the way of solution code. The example was for explainability.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much again for all the help. I appreciate the quick response. I hope you have a great day.